# PhoneGap File Transfer corrupts .mp3 when uploading to server

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I'm messing around with PhoneGap for a project, but i'm having some trouble uploading an .mp3

I'm able to record the mp3 using the device's in-built microphone, and I'm then able to upload the file using the following JavaScript:

```
var audio_name = 'fyp_app_recording_' + Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000) + '.mp3';

// Record audio
// 
function recordAudio() {

    var src = audio_name;
    var mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess(src), onError);

    // Record audio
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
        recTime = recTime + 1;
        setAudioPosition("Recording Audio - " + recTime + " sec");
        if (recTime >= 10) {
            clearInterval(recInterval);
            mediaRec.stopRecord();
            setAudioPosition("Recording Saved As " + src);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

// onSuccess Callback
//
function onSuccess(src) {
    console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success" + src);
}

// onError Callback 
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Set audio position
// 
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}

//File upload

    function uploadAudio() {    

      var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName="test.mp3";
        options.mimeType="audio/mpeg";

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload("mnt/sdcard/" + audio_name, "http://www.richardsonweb.co.uk/fyp/test1/upload.php", win, fail, options);
    }

    function win() {
        alert("Yay! It worked!");
    }

    function 7(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
    }
```

The upload.php file contains the following code:

```
    print_r($_FILES);



$new_file_name = time() . ".mp3";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$new_file_name);
```

However, when I then download the file from my FTP client, Windows Media Player claims the file is corrupted.

Oddly, the file sort of plays fine in VLC (the progress bar jams at 10 seconds, and doesn't move, but it plays the audio perfectly).

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this php code

```
<?php
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . time() . ".mp3";

   ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "3200000000");

   if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help (this does still move the file onto the server) but for some reason the file is still corrupted. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: maybe it's the max file upload limit try this setting ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "3200000000");

Comment: @LiamRichardson, why did you accepted the answer, setting the upload_max_filesize solved the problem for you?

Comment: @ClintonWard, I am having the same problem as LiamRichardson, but I don't understand how your answer helped him resolve his problem. Can you please explain? Thanks.